# How can I re-export everything from a TS file and still be able to modify one of exported members value?

Tags: typescript

I want to re-export everything from one ts file like this:

```
export * from "./my-module";
```

However, I would like to modify one value from that module, and I only know it exported one value called `Foo`, I won't be able to know other exported members.

I want to do this:

```
import { Foo as oldFoo, ...rest } from "./my-module"

export {...rest} from "./my-module";

export const Foo = {
  ...oldFoo,
  newProperty: 'BAR'
}
```

I want to do this because I want to keep track of third-party libraries ' updates, of course, I can know all the exported members, but once I upgrade my package, exported members from the third-party libraries might change.

Is it possible to do this?